# Start Ubuntu Desktop from terminal using WSL?

Tags: 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In Windows 10 I installed WSL and then installed Ubuntu. How do I get access to the Ubuntu Desktop GUI?

Comment: Unfortunately all of the answers on the two duplicates (even the one I suggested) are out of date.  Please check back in regularly -- I'm planning on updating my answer, but I just haven't had a chance yet.